# Why did Bail Organa decide not to travel to Tatooine?

Tags: star-wars, obi-wan-kenobi-2022

In Episode 5 of *Obi-Wan Kenobi*, Bail Organa leaves a message for Obi-Wan, informing him that he will be traveling to Tatooine to assist the Lars with young Luke. Yet in Episode 6, Bail apparently "changed his plans" without having been contacted by Obi-Wan.

Comment: I don't think there's any evidence that Obi-Wan *didn't* contact him; we just don't see it on-screen.

Comment: It turns out he hates sand too.

Comment: @chepner Well, the end of Episode 5 had me wondering about how Obi-Wan was going to stop Bail from traveling to the Lars homestead on Tatooine. Then Bail never shows up. It's like a continuity error.

Comment: I think the point of that particular scene was for Obi-Wan to realize he had *dropped* the communicator and thus someone else might hear the contents of the message, raising suspicions about what "boy" is on Tatooine who an Imperial Senator is showing interest in. (Which of course, someone else *did*.)

Answer (score 6):

The actual line is

> If I don't hear from you soon, I'll head to Tatooine.

Not that much time occurs between episodes 5 and 6, so it would appear that Bail hadn't decided to go to Tatooine yet.

Also note that they're trying to avoid communicating.

> I know you said no communication but your silence worries me.

Comment: This is correct. He said "if I don't hear from you soon, I'll go to Tatooine". The next day (or maybe 2 days?) Leia was back in Alderaan and Obi Wan went to visit.